# function to mask sensitive characters with asterisks in PHP

Tags: php, function, masking

Okays guys, I need a function to mask the credit card number, expiry date and cvv of these two strings:

```
[orderId] => 212939129
[orderNumber] => INV10001
[salesTax] => 1.00
[amount] => 21.00
[terminal] => 5
[currency] => 1
[type] => purchase
[avsStreet] => 123 Road
[avsZip] => A1A 2B2
[customerCode] => CST1001
[cardId] => 18951828182
[cardHolderName] => John Smith
[cardNumber] => 5454545454545454
[cardExpiry] => 1025
[cardCVV] => 100


Request=Credit Card.Auth Only&Version=4022&HD.Network_Status_Byte=*&HD.Application_ID=TZAHSK!&HD.Terminal_ID=12991kakajsjas&HD.Device_Tag=000123&07.POS_Entry_Capability=1&07.PIN_Entry_Capability=0&07.CAT_Indicator=0&07.Terminal_Type=4&07.Account_Entry_Mode=1&07.Partial_Auth_Indicator=0&07.Account_Card_Number=4242424242424242&07.Account_Expiry=1024&07.Transaction_Amount=142931&07.Association_Token_Indicator=0&17.CVV=200&17.Street_Address=123 Road SW&17.Postal_Zip_Code=90210&17.Invoice_Number=INV19291
```

It needs to take in both and return the strings in the same format except the info required with asterisks.

I have no idea how to approach this. I know how to do simple masking, REGEX etc... I just am not familiar enough with php to get it done.

Comment: have you tried to google it first? `php credit card number mask` yield a lot of resources regarding it. some of them even pointing here on stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413886/mask-credit-card-number-in-php and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110891/masking-credit-card-number and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246702/how-to-mask-credit-card-number-mask-in-a-text there's a lot

Comment: Yeah, in these examples it only takes in the cc number - it needs to be able to take in either string and produce three masked sections...

Comment: you need to at least have an attempt at it. there's no hurt in trying. it can be modified to your fitting